# Generating piano notes using the Karplus-Strong Algorithm

Tags: filters, audio

I am trying to get a piano A4(440 Hz) sound from the MATLAB. I have looked at this link https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/generating-guitar-chords-using-the-karplus-strong-algorithm.html which uses the Karplus-Strong Algorithm to get a vibrating string effect. Then, an IIR filter to get a guitar sound. But in piano, we have a different pitch for a particular frequency. How can I modify this filter to get a piano sound? Or should I get the piano sound from the Karplus-Strong Implementation directly without using any filter? The problem is, in piano, we have different contributions from the harmonics, so I should be able to control the contribution of each harmonic (880Hz 1320Hz 1760Hz, etc.)? If so, how can I do that?

```
clc;close all  %KARPLUS-STRONG IMPLEMENTATION
freqHz=440;
iterations=40000;
fs=44100;

N = fs/freqHz;
N = floor(N);
x = 2*rand(1,N);
x = x - mean(x);
% generate noise and init. delay line
% make sure burst and delay line agree: burst >= delay line
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
y  = [zeros(1,N+1)];
if iterations > length(x)
    diff = iterations - length(x);
    x  = [x zeros(1,diff)];
end
% Filtering
% y[n] = x[n] + 0.5 y[n-N] + 0.5 y[n-(N+1)]
% init.
out    = 0;
signal = 0;
lengthYOffset = length(y)-1;
for i=1:iterations
    out = x(i) + 0.5*(y(N) + y(N+1));   
    % filter signal
    y = [out, y(1:lengthYOffset)];     
    % update delay line
    signal = [signal out];
end

figure;
plot(signal), grid on,title('Simple Karplus Strong algorithm'),sound(signal, fs)
```

The IRR filter in the MATLAB help page:

```
clc;clear;close all
Fs=44100;
A=440;
delay = round(Fs/A);

F = linspace(1/Fs, 6000, 2^12);
b  = firls(200, [0 1/delay 2/delay 3/delay 4 /delay 1], [0 0 1 1 1 1]);
a  = [1 zeros(1, delay) -0.6 -0.9 -0.3];
[H,W] = freqz(b, a, F, Fs);
plot(W, 20*log10(abs(H)));
title('Harmonics of an open A string');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Magnitude (dB)');
```